# Multiple splines in one plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, spline

I am a newbie to R and I'm trying to generate a simple scatter plot with multiple spline fits in them.

I have a table that looks like below,

```
chr     window  number  percent pie  
chr1    500     15      0.502   na  
chr1    1000    21      0.641   0.019704955  
chr1    1500    21      0.621   0.016777844  
chr1    2000    22      0.534   na  
chr1    2500    35      0.698   0.028712731  
chr2    4500    2       0.371   na    
chr2    5000    3       0.342   na    
chr4    5500    1       0.068   na    
chr4    6000    0       0.000   na    
chr4    6500    0       0.000   na    
chr5    7000    2       0.079   na    
chr5    7500    12      0.440   na
```

What I would like to do is essentially plot a simple x,y scatterplot from this data frame and add spline fits for each level in column 1 on the same plot. Now I can generate a scatterplot like this,

```
ggplot(Y, aes(x=percent, y=pie))+ geom_point(size = 1)  +
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8))
```

but all the examples that I have seen so far are about having one spline per plot. My question is how can I split my data frame based on column1 and generate spline for each subset and finally have all splines in the same plot as the scatterplot?

I prefer to keep this inside ggplot but if you have solutions outside of ggplot please let me know those too.

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if you need more information from my side.

Cheers,

Comment: Does `geom_smooth` do what you want, by any chance? (If not, please consider elaborating on what your desired output would look like, especially in comparison to those "examples that you have seen so far*). You can add multiple `geom_*` layers, of course.

Comment: You can try adding `colour = chr` to `aes()`, and then use `stat_smooth()` for your spline fit as exemplified in its documentation (http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_smooth.html)

Comment: @maj- I'll be more elaborate here. So if you look at the table above there are five levels in column1 (chr1,chr2,...chr5). My final output will be one scatterplot generated from all the values in this table with 5 splines (that correspond to a layer each in column 1). Is this clear?

Comment: @Hugo - I tried that but I'm getting only one spline. Not sure if I'm doing it right. 

c <- ggplot(Y, aes(x=percent, y=pie, colour = factor(Chr)))+ geom_point(size = 1)  + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8))
c + stat_smooth(aes(group=1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some data for the `Y$pie<-rnorm(12)` variable since there was only 3 values.

```
ggplot(Y, aes(x=percent, y=pie,color=chr))+ geom_point(size = 3)  +
         theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8)) + 
         geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, size=1,show_guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Does that come closer to what you are asking?

Comment: this come close to what I'm after but when I tried this I got dots with different colours as we would expect but only one spline curve? I thought maybe the lines overlapped and so I tried other methods too but none of those seem to work :( Any pointers?

Comment: are you using more data for the `pie` variable? right now it only has data for one of the levels in `chr`

Comment: Yes, the table I have has over 17000 rows in it. This is a head from the table.

Comment: @user2960593 is your single spline curve coloured as one of the `chr` values? If it is, then it might be that you don't have sufficient points to do a fit in the remaining chromosomes. Try to check this by doing `table(Y$chr, !is.na(Y$pie))`. Hopefully, you should get high counts being `TRUE` (that is, not NA values).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. This worked. Turned out that the percent values were stored as character types and that was the cause of the problem. Upon changing it to numeric this solution worked. This was a weird given that the percent values were a result of division operation. Anyway I'm glad that it worked. Thanks again.